Why was this question closed (too niche?)
I asked this question of general topology a day or two ago.  Admittedly it is a "niche" topic, which will attract people interested in general topology and maybe not many people outside of it.  But it received two interesting answers and both the question and its answers got a good number of positive votes, indicating the interest in them.
(I agree with FShrike in his nomination statement for moderator elections (https://math.stackexchange.com/election), when he says: "we could make the "does it have future value?" quibble with niche, high-quality questions - but many niche questions can be very interesting, and we should be proud of our ability to be able to answer technically expert, niche questions.")
Now, according to the timeline for the post, after this initial positive reception, for some unknown reason the question was marked as a "hot network question", and then closed in short order with the reason ""Not suitable for this site".  Also

"Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc."

As far as I can tell, the original question did provide several of these things.  In particular, relevant definitions for the involved terms were provided by links to the relevant definitions for the convenience of readers.  Source was provided by a link to a paper listing the statement.  I also mentioned that the paper said the result was "not difficult", thus making it a good choice to post on MSE.
In my mind, one of the main goals of this site is to serve as a repository for high quality questions and answers.  Before asking the question, I did an extensive search on the site (and also on mathoverflow) and did not find any relevant post.  This was an indication that it would be interesting to add the question to this site, so that any future users interested in this topic would be able to find information about it.
For background info, I was led to the existence of this paper by a comment someone added to my answer to a different question.  The fact I was trying to get a proof of was mentioned in passing in the introduction to the paper as supposedly a basic fact about the topic of Lindelof scattered spaces.  But adding how I got from the other question to the paper really does not seem relevant in providing "motivation for the question".  Basically, my motivation was: it seems an interesting result, easy to state, presumably not hard to prove, and not available on the site.  Writing exactly that in the question seems kind of silly though.
Basically, I am curious to know more of the reasons the post was closed and what the people who closed it were expecting to see.

Question was re-opened. In the future try to elaborate more in the body of the question.

The question was just asking to be closed. There was no indication that the person posting it had put in any work whatsoever. There was no indication that the person posting it even knew the definition of any of the terms in it. The question was about as far from self-contained as logically possible. People here jump on questions like that, and squash them to pieces. Look: you've got to sell a question if you want it to fly with this crowd. You've got to define your terms, not direct users offsite to understand the question. You've got to give some indication that you actually (continued)

(continued) understand the question you're asking, that you have thought about it a little bit, that you know what's at stake, mathematically speaking, that you know where the difficulty lies. It might be a better website if voters gave posters the benefit of the doubt and assumed they knew what they were talking about, but this website hasn't worked that way for years (if it ever did). Follow site customs, or prepare to get shafted.

Thanks for the comments.  It is no big deal that the question was closed (and now reopened). I was asking here to know the level of detail that needs to be provided as justification.  Now I know better what is expected here.

Your question obviously should not have been closed, but unfortunately most voters mindlessly just assume that a short question has insufficient context.

@EricWofsey I don't know why you think that the question "obviously" should not have been closed.  The version of the question which was closed was:  "Every hereditarily Lindelöf scattered space is countable.
This paper says it is "not difficult to prove". Can anyone provide a proof?"  (with couple of links).  Personally, that version of the question looks like a textbook example of a contextless problem statement question.  The current version, in my opinion, is much improved.

Hi! I see I have been quoted. The new revision of your question is nice; I would say that while I definitely support niche questions, niche questions should still make some attempt to be readable by people not yet in that niche. Not least because the same words can mean different things in different contexts, and also to maximise potential educational value. I didn't see it until just now, but certainly the original version of the question wasn't closed for being 'too niche' but just too terse. This is less of a reply to you and more a clarification of my position

@EricWofsey I understand where your sentiment comes from. But a related practical problem is that the questions, by their sheer volume, need to be reviewed by a crowd of volunteers. If you are unhappy with the level of reviewing, you can fix the matter by reviewing questions en masse yourself. Anyway, the site has developed egalitarian quality requirements that questions at all levels should meet. It is, for better or for worse, intellectually honest to do so.
